# System has delay before shutdown

Tags: unity, 20.04, shutdown

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.1, Unity Remix, on a laptop and one of the problems is that it won't shutdown/reboot until 10-20 seconds has passed.

It only happens when I shutdown/reboot through UI, if I do shutdown now it closes instanteneous.

Any ideeas what is happening? The system is a fresh install.

Comment: In a terminal windows I would run a `dmesg -w` and/or a `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and see if there are any messages/clues from the time you issue the command to the time it actually shuts down. Or make a note of the exact times to the second and have a look at your log files for those times.

Comment: After selecting shutdown from the UI, hit the ESC key to view the shutdown processes. Where it stops/pauses for a long time will give you a clue.

Comment: Same problem here, @codlord, `dmesg -w` does not show anything new, and its hard to read syslog so fast. I noticed that if you doe not login on the desktop, the shutdown on the lock screen is expected normal fast. [ESC] does nothing after hit shutdown

Comment: I *think* this has something to do with lightdm, if i login via gui, open a terminal, become root and execute `systemctl stop lightdm` after i click on "shutdown", every thing works normal and fast as usally. Any idea how/why ?

Comment: I haven't managed to do anything with this issue. Funny thing is, sometimes it shutdowns normally, sometimes not. I cannot pinpoint the issue.